# CakePHP $this->Auth->user('id') returns incorrect user in controller

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I've got a really bizarre bug occurring in a CakePHP app I've been working on.

I've got the following method in my users_controller.php that reads the currently signed in user and sends the data to a view and sets the title_for_layout to the user's name:-

```
function account() {
    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $this->set('User', $this->User->read());
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Welcome '.$this->User->Contact->field('name'));
}
```

In my view I've got (among other things):-

```
<?php echo $User['Contact']['name'] ?>
```

Everything in the view looks fine. It is outputting the fields for the correct user (the one I am currently signed in as). However the title_for_layout is using a completely different user's details. So `$this->User->Contact->field('name')` is not the same as `$User['Contact']['name']`!

I can't spot what is going wrong here so hoping someone out there can point out my mistake.

Comment: I have a tip, we also use `$_SESSION ['Auth'] ['User'] ['id']` for get current user's id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model `read()` simply does a `find('first')`, sets the result as the Model `$data`, and returns it. It doesn't set `$id`s of associated models.

So in your case, `$this->User->id` is set, but `$this->User->Contact->id` isn't.

Comment: Thanks. Looking back at the code again this makes complete sense. Issue sorted. :)